# Dataannotation Foreignkey property name vs column name?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in my domain classes with EF5 and framework 4.5

```
public class SalesOrderLine : LoggedEntity
    {
       [ForeignKey("SalesLine")]
       [Required]
       public int SalesLine_Id { get; set; }
       public SalesLine SalesLine { get; set; }
  }
```

However the [example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319366/EF-Code-First-Add-a-Foreign-Key-relationship) uses the column name as the foreign key, not the navigation property name.
Is there any difference between the two ways of doing it?

[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. Both usages do the same.

Which is clear or not clear depending on if you are using EF 5 with .NET 4.0 or with .NET 4.5.

In .NET 4.0 (where the `ForeignKeyAttribute` class is part of the `EntityFramework.dll` assembly) the description you'll see in Intellisense (when hovering over the attribute for example) says (emphasis by me):

> Denotes a property used as a foreign key in a relationship.  The
>   annotation **may be placed on the foreign key property** and specify the
>   associated navigation property name, **or placed on a navigation
>   property** and specify the associated foreign key name.

In .NET 4.5 (where the `ForeignKeyAttribute` class has been moved into the framework's `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly) the description has become as informative as a tautology:

> Denotes a property used as a foreign key in a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted shows how to use EF Code-first to create the navigation property of Manager and map it to type Person -

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    // The following will use ManagerId as the foreign key and map it to PersonId, or w/e the key field is for person
    [ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
    public Person Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Your code uses SalesLine_Id to establish the foreign key relationship to the SalesLine, which is of type SalesLine.

```
public class SalesOrderLine : LoggedEntity { 
    [ForeignKey("SalesLine")] 
    [Column("SalesLine_Id")]  
    [Required] 
    public int SalesLine_Id { get; set; } 
    public SalesLine SalesLine { get; set; } 
}
```

What's important to understand is that you probably don't have to decorate your class with all of the annotations that you are, unless you are using an odd naming convention, because EF will automatically map everything the way you want it to provided the names are fairly consistent -

```
public class SalesOrderLine {
    public int SalesOrderLineId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SalesLineId { get; set; } 
    public virtual SalesLine SalesLine { get; set; } 
}

public class SalesLine {
    public int SalesLineId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SalesOrderLine> SalesOrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

Would work just fine, as an example.  If you need to make the relationship any more complicated you will probably need to start looking at using the Fluent API for configurations, but as is that code would work fine without dataannotations.  Since SalesLineId is not nullable it is required, EF understands it is a foreign key, and everything is happy.

Comment: Interesting. However all my primary keys are called Id, so I do need to tell EF which table the FK should map to.  I am confused that there are 2 ways apparently, although I can only get one of them to work.

Comment: Well if it is still early in development and you can use the default convention I would use 'SalesLeadId' instead of SalesLead_Id you will make your life easier.

Comment: Why is SalesLeadId better than SalesLead_Id?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx because it is either Id alone or the class name followed by Id.  Lookup convention over configuration, it's one of the things that makes ef codefirst so strong

Comment: Strangely enough I have columns with the _Id name because EF created them , when i was using framework 4 and  not stating the FK Name

Comment: I asked why ~http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050590/why-does-ef5-create-foreign-keys-with-id-but-recommend-naming-convention-id-wi~